# creating and accessing session variable on linux server - play 1.2.5

Tags: java, ubuntu, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have created a play .1.2.5 application on windows. I deployed that application on Linux Ubuntu server. When I run the application on the server, I am getting an error near session variable.

`Error: "NumberFormatException occured : null".`

I have an idea why this error occurred (as can't typecast null) but Session variable should have been created on the server before that. Any help is appreciated. thanks.

```
  long nCustomerID=Long.parseLong(Session.current().get("customerId"));
```

Comment: just to make things clear : you totally can typecast null. you can't parseLong it, though

Comment: it would be useful to see the full stack trace. Also, are you sure customerId is guaranteed not to be null?

Comment: have you tried to get the values of Session, Session.current() and Session.current().get("customerId")?